# Is it possible to run the Teensy to the Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, teensy

I'm already done copying/pasting the libraries that I know is needed to run the program, but I wonder why I always get this error every time I tried to run the code. What do you think would be the possible reason why I get this error:

```
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp:64:14: warning:       
  #warning Using current Arduino IDE with Wire library is functionally  
  limiting.   [-Wcpp]

  #warning Using current Arduino IDE with Wire library is functionally limiting.

          ^

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp:65:14: warning: 
  #warning Arduino IDE v1.0.1+ with I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE implementation   
  is recommended. [-Wcpp]

  #warning Arduino IDE v1.0.1+ with I2CDEV_BUILTIN_FASTWIRE implementation 
  is recommended.

          ^

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp:66:14: warning:
 #warning This I2Cdev implementation does not support: [-Wcpp]

 #warning This I2Cdev implementation does not support:

          ^

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\I2Cdev\I2Cdev.cpp:67:14: warning: 
 #warning - Timeout detection (some Wire requests block forever) [-Wcpp]

 #warning - Timeout detection (some Wire requests block forever)

          ^

 In file included from C:\Program Files     
 (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp:27:0:

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp: In member  
 function 'bool RTIMUHal::HALRead(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned 
 char, unsigned char*, const char*)':

 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.h:59:37: error:   
'class HardwareSerial' has no member named 'printf'

 #define HAL_ERROR1(m, x)     Serial.printf(m, x);

                                 ^

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp:73:13: note:  
in expansion of macro 'HAL_ERROR1'

         HAL_ERROR1("I2C read failed - %s\n", errorMsg);

         ^

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp: In member   
  function 'bool RTIMUHal::HALWrite(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned 
  char, const unsigned char*, const char*)':

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.h:59:37: error:  
  'class HardwareSerial' has no member named 'printf'

  #define HAL_ERROR1(m, x)     Serial.printf(m, x);

                                 ^

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp:96:13: 
  note: in expansion of macro 'HAL_ERROR1'

         HAL_ERROR1("I2C write failed - %s\n", errorMsg);

         ^

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp: In member    
   function 'bool RTIMUHal::HALWrite(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned 
   char, const char*)':

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.h:59:37: 
   error: 'class HardwareSerial' has no member named 'printf'

   #define HAL_ERROR1(m, x)     Serial.printf(m, x);

                                 ^

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries\RTIMULib\RTIMUHal.cpp:119:13: 
  note: in expansion of macro 'HAL_ERROR1'

         HAL_ERROR1("I2C write failed - %s\n", errorMsg);

         ^

  exit status 1
  Error compiling.
```

Comment: Please add some information about the Arduino/Teensy IDE version, board, libraries used, etc. The compiler (and the source code) is trying to tell you that you have a severe configuration issue.

Comment: Many of your problems seem to be that you are trying to use Linux software on an Arduino. That's never going to work.

Comment: It just seems he's missing the right print function. It's worth a shot just  replacing the "printf" with "print". @Thomas, have you tried it (go to libraries folder, RTIMULib and open RTIMUHal in notepad and change line 59 "printf" to "print", keep everything else the same)?

Comment: Replacing "printf" with "print" will only lead to the "dark side" - even more compiler warnings. It might be the wrong version of the RTIMULib library.

Comment: Hi guys thank you so much for your responds :)

Comment: @Mikael Patel https://github.com/richards-tech/RTIMULib2-Teensy here is the link .

Comment: @Majenko, so you mean there's no chance to work it ?

Comment: @Avamander, i'll try it .

Comment: @MikaelPatel, yes i  used the teensy library because this is the latest,  a need to add the runtime calibration which is not present in this library. https://github.com/richards-tech/RTIMULib-Arduino